# JavaFX, Alt+Num (0-127) different for Java 7u80 (gibberish) vs Java 8u202 (normal ASCII), both default chatset UTF-8

Tags: java-8, ascii, javafx-2, java-7

I have an ooold JavaFX project (2015), where I have to add scanner functionality.
Scanner typically sends characters through a sequence of ALT+Num.
For example ALT+(Num5 followed by Num0) results in character representing 2.
This very same behavior happens by hitting Keyboard buttons.
Problem is unrelated to the scanner. I will explain later down why.
Keyboard layout is US throughout the whole testing and running stuff.

This works flawlessly when compiled in Java 8 (oracle archive, update 202 under).
But in Java 7 (oracle archive, update 80) returns weird characters.
I didn't recognize those, nor as any human languange, nor as ascii (or extended ascii https://www.asciitable.com/).

- Java 8: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;23.266.007 (being proper)
- Java 7: “ß|ß‡ß’ßß¨ß+ß¾ß|‡r|¨¨rˆˆ+ (being wrong)

Characters are retrieved by event filter KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, keyEvent.getCharacter()

Compiled with IntelliJ IDEA. Win11,

- Java 7 with language level "7 - Diamonds".
- Java 8 with language level "8 - Lambdas".

Is there anything in combination JavaFX 2.2.3 with Java7 vs Java8
which could possibly change the basic ASCII table into something else?

First thing I checked was Charset.defaultCharset(), but that returned UTF-8 for both java versions.
Even though the scanner is used only to scan Numbers, . (dot), / (slash) and - (minus)
from the very basic 127 first characters of ASCII, so that wouldn't be affected by code page?
Doesn't matter if scanned by device or typed from keyboard.

Scanner explanation: Regardless of Java version, scanner does input (ALT + Num5 + Num5).
But in case of Java 8 it's ASCII '7' as expected. In the Java7 it's a '+' if I remember correctly.
Even if I use the keyboard and Alt+Num5+Num5 method, I get the same characters as the scanner does,
for each Java version.

I did an additional test with the Java 7 and a notepad window.
Notepad showed the scanned numbers in the correct format 12.345.678,
but the java application had complete gibberish.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It’s a normal thing that older software versions have problems which are fixed in newer versions. So if the application works as intended in the ancient Java 8, why do you care whether it works in an even older Java version?

Comment: Projekt is running on JRE 7. It would take a huge effort to repass is to current state of technologies. It would be great to just tell that JRE7+JavaFX2  to use the basic ASCII somehow.

Comment: Nobody talked about “current state of technologies” so far. The discussion was about Java 7 and Java 8. So, to get it correctly: this project is running under Java 7 and has the described problem right from day one (for eight years now)?

Comment: It runs on Java 7 from the start, yes. Leadership just recently decided, that it would be great to use a scanner. So the task was delegated to me and I, using the scanner, discovered this weird behaviour. Until now nobody tried to type ALT+NUM using the keyboard, so nobody knew :)

Comment: I see. But this doesn’t sound like a big problem to me. They want a new feature, they have to migrate to a new Java version. That’s not unusual. Of course, finding an associated bug report would be nice, but who wants to do that archaeology…